# Windows Mobile/Compact Framework: Detect form move

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a compact framework forms application that, among other things, displays popup windows that are not the full window size.

As things stand, it is possible when one of these popups is displayed to drag it off of the visible screen area using the title bar. This then gives the impression of the form being unresponsive because the popup is waiting for input but invisible.

I would therefore like to detect the moving of the form so that I can reset the position and keep it centred on screen. However, I do not seem to be able to achieve this.

So far, I have tried sub-classing the form and then looking for WM_MOVE, WM_SIZE or WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED messages - however I never see these messages in the WndProc (I have also tried logging all messages but once the form is displayed it receives no messages whilst moving or after being moved, in fact once displayed the next message in WndProc is when a button is clicked on the form).

I have also tried detecting the current location of the form during the OnPaint/OnPaintBackground events. This works, as long as the form does not contain a MainMenu control. If the MainMenu control exists, you can drag the form down to the bottom of the screen under where the menu is and the OnPaint/OnPaintBackground events no longer fire (it does not need to be repainted as it is no longer visible).

I am running out of ideas; any suggestions?

Comment: Might not be important, but the form is being created and then SetWindowLong called to apply WS_BORDER, WS_POPUP and WS_CAPTION. I am then also calling SHDoneButton with SHDB_HIDE to hide the default "Ok" button in the title bar.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the form and changes the layout? All Forms of compact framework are dialogs. Dialog windows have there own Message Loop (DlgProc). Did you try implementing the MessageWindow class inside the forms code?

Answer (score 4):

I did just update my Moveable WinForm solution: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/11/07/mobile-development-move-your-form/.

[image]

The updated source code is at http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FMoveableWinForm%2FMovableForm

the essential subclassing code to get msg send to form is (see winapi.cs):

```
    #region subclassing
    public class subclassForm:IDisposable
    {
        #region delegate_event_stuff
        public class wndprocEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public IntPtr hWnd;
            public uint msg;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public wndprocEventArgs(IntPtr lphWnd, uint iMsg, IntPtr lpLParam, IntPtr lpWParam)
            {
                hWnd = lphWnd;
                msg = iMsg;
                lParam = lpLParam;
                wParam = lpWParam;
            }
        }

        public delegate void wndProcEventHandler(object sender, wndprocEventArgs wndProcArgs);
        public event wndProcEventHandler wndProcEvent;
        void onWndProcEvent(wndprocEventArgs wa)
        {
            if (this.wndProcEvent == null)
                return;
            wndProcEvent(this, wa);
        }
        #endregion

        public enum WNDMSGS:uint{
            WM_MOVE=0x0003,
            WM_SIZE=0x0005,
        }
        public subclassForm(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
        {
            _form = form;
            lpPrevWndFunc = _subClassForm(_form);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            unsubClassForm(_form);
        }
        IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc=IntPtr.Zero;
        System.Windows.Forms.Form _form;

        static WndProcDelegate persistentWndProc;
        IntPtr _subClassForm(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
        {
            //avoid multiple subclassing
            if (lpPrevWndFunc != IntPtr.Zero)
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            persistentWndProc = WndProc;
            lpPrevWndFunc = (IntPtr)GetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC);
            SetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, persistentWndProc);
            return lpPrevWndFunc;
        }
        IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HWND: " + hWnd + " MSG: " + msg + " WPARAM: " + wParam + " LPARAM: " + lParam);
            onWndProcEvent(new wndprocEventArgs(hWnd, msg, lParam, wParam));
            return CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        bool unsubClassForm(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
        {
            bool bRet = false;
            if (lpPrevWndFunc == IntPtr.Zero)
                return bRet;
            if (SetWindowLong(form.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, lpPrevWndFunc.ToInt32()) != 0)
            {
                bRet = true;
                lpPrevWndFunc = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            return bRet;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

with the code you should be able to 'recognize' if the form is moved and possibly outside the primary screens boundaries.

Comment: That's cool, josef. I was going to suggest he put a timer in there and reset the form location on the Timer_Tick event.

Comment: This is actually pretty much what I am doing to try and receive the message in the first place. I simply do not receive the WM_SIZE or WM_MOVE messages. I wonder why it is that you are seeing them when I do not?

Comment: By the way; +1 for what is a very detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dumb solution, but have you considered putting a Timer on the form?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer CheckLocation { get; set; }
    private Point FirstLocation { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FirstLocation = Location;
        CheckLocation.Tick += new EventHandler(CheckLocation_Tick);
    }

    void CheckLocation_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FirstLocation != Location)
        {
            Location = FirstLocation;
        }
    }
}
```